# TIBCO Spotfire - How to divide two calculated values on graphical table?

Tags: spotfire, tibco

[image: Sample of Calls Status Spotfire]

Edited : Attached picture should explain.

All what is need is to add something to below expression in order to get the percentage % of **Accepted** and **Rejected** out of **All**

Comment: I'm confused from your question. How your original data looks like? What exactly you want to do? What do you mean by "graphical table"? Why do you want to use "custom expressions" instead of just using simple aggregation? ... Please post some sample data with desired output.

Comment: You wouldn't do this in limit data, instead use the custom expression as a new value for the graphical table.

Comment: @OsamaWaly can you edit your question and provide a sample data set? You'll need a date or month column at a minimum.

Comment: @scsimon thanks for your reply, how to write an expression that does this. i need to write a custom expression to get the value of the total count for only a specified filter value ... for example : if the first calculated value is all calls = 2000 , i want the second column which is the rejected calls to calculate the rejected of the 2000 .. hope you can help thanks

Comment: @scsimon  example : the data is loaded with no filters selected and on the graphical table i have months on left and three calculated members : ALL CALLS  , Accepted CALLS  , and Rejected CALLS.  

ALL CALLS by default will be the correct value
Accecpted calls should be the number filtered by Accecpted

Comment: @OsamaWaly you need to add the data to your original question.

Comment: @scsimon :
I have a calculated measure called Calls_Count which equal 2000 and a filter called  call_status which has two attributes : Accepted or Rejected.

What i want: create a graphical table that have 3 columns of calculated values :

All : Already counted with 2000 since there is no filters are applied

Accepted : how to write an expression to choose the calls_count with a filtered call_status = Accepted ????

Rejected : how to write an expression to choose the calls_count with a filtered call_status = Rejected????

Comment: @scsimon

When i choose Custom expression i find : Default ([Calls_count]) which result with 2000

how to make it Default ([Calls_count]) for Status="Accecpted"  ??

Hope its clear now
Thanks

Comment: @scsimon sample data inserted

Comment: How do you determine what is January from February

Comment: @scsimon i have edited the description and attached a picture

Comment: @OsamaWaly you need to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with emphasis on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We aren't a coding service. We are here to help, but you have to do your part first. I've already take extreme measures to try and help you explain your question clearly. You can't expect help when you don't provide accurate sample data and expected results. "I need" doesn't work here.

Comment: @scsimon ok i will review the links you provided. I have tried to provide you with all the information but it seems its not matched with what you need in order to help.
Anyway, thanks and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression like sum(if( [Tx Status] = "Accepted",[Value/Cloumn]) this will add only rows that have [Tx Status] = "Accepted" 
but if You filtered out [Tx Status] you will not see any data :)